# Sending hidden input field values comes back null

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have one input field that is hidden.  I'm using it as a placeholder to send the value to a scriptlet.  Like below, but the value of the hidden field is always null.  When I remove the hidden tag everything works correctly.

```
  <form method=post action="test.jsp">

  <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" >

  <button class="button primary" type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

Then in scriplet getting the value, but it is nullpointer exception

```
           <%
            String x = null;

            x  = request.getParameter("name");

            %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a `value` for your input hidden field. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
```

[Try it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden)

Answer (score 0):

It should come, only disabled fields data u will not getting in req.getParameters()

u missed value attribute